# How to create Friendship model in Prisma?

Tags: database, model, nestjs, backend, prisma

I'm currently creating something like Facebook and got stuck while trying to model Friendship in Prisma.

**My current User model:**

```
model User {
id String @id

handle String @unique

created_at DateTime @default(now())
updated_at DateTime @updatedAt

account Account @relation(fields: \[id\], references: \[id\])
}
```

**My current Friendship model:**

```
model Friendship {
  id String @id @default(cuid())

  user_id String
  user    User   @relation(name: "friendships", fields: [user_id], references: [id])

  friend_id String
  friend    User   @relation(name: "friendships", fields: [friend_id], references: [id])

  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime @updatedAt

  @@unique([user_id, friend_id])
@@unique([friend_id, user_id])
}
```

I'm getting an error: Error validating model "Friendship": Wrongly named relation detected. The fields `user` and `friend` in model `Friendship` both use the same relation name. Please provide different relation names for them through `@relation().

As described before, I've tried to create Friendship model in Prisma, however I'm getting an error: Error validating model "Friendship": Wrongly named relation detected. The fields `user` and `friend` in model `Friendship` both use the same relation name. Please provide different relation names for them through `@relation().

Answer (score 0):

could you try

```
model Friendship {
  id String @id @default(cuid())

  user_id String
  user    User   @relation(name: "user_friendships", fields: [user_id], references: [id])

  friend_id String
  friend    User   @relation(name: "friend_friendships", fields: [friend_id], references: [id])

  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime @updatedAt

  @@unique([user_id, friend_id])
  @@unique([friend_id, user_id])
}
```

because you're using the same relation name, "friendships," for both the "user" and "friend" fields in the Friendship model

Comment: I am not sure if I undestand. What would I have to include in the User model?